# How to save ansible stdout.lines to a file is in list format

Tags: ansible

Need to save std.out lines to a file in delegated host using below playbook.
I am able to save the data, but the saved data is in json format. I need this data as list format as like command output.

```
- name: Host Collection
  hosts:  rcht01
  tasks:
    - name: Host coll
      shell:    mysql -ulnx -plnx  -D inventory -se "select Host_Name from servers where OS= 'Linux' AND Server_Status = 'Live' AND Server_loc = 'Richardson' "| tr 'A-Z' 'a-z'
      register: all_hosts_list

    - name: Saving data to local file
      copy:
        content:  "{{  all_hosts_list.stdout_lines  }}"
        dest: /tmp/host_coll
      delegate_to: rchabs01
```

Answer (score 2):

```
        content:  "{{  all_hosts_list.stdout_lines|join('\n')  }}"
```

Comment: This answer, as it currently stands, may possibly be correct (I would not know), but it lacks any sort of explaining.

Answer (score 1):

This line worked better for me:

```
content: "{{ output.stdout_lines | join('\n') }}\n"
```

It adds a final LF which is otherwise omitted.

The join function "concatenates a list into a string" using the character provided in the parameter as the separator between list items. The output first exists as a list, without line terminators; the join() converts the list to a single string with LFs at the end of each former list item. Except for the final \n, which I added above.

Docs: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Since you post is mainly an improvement over the [other answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/580104/377345) rather than a different approach, you may want to consider submitting an edit suggestion to that answer instead of posting it here.